# aggregate in nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to create a sum of taskAssembly.labour of each taskAssembly object and put it in the totalLabour field

see this plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/rKnup0IIPRYvh8JLHXbD?p=preview

see my data:

```
{ "client": "client1","takeoff": [{
"taskName": "ToW",
 "taskQnt": 2300,
"totalLabour":"",
"taskAssembly": [
  {
    "taskName": "ToW",
    "taskQnt": 2300,
    "taskLabour": 22,
    "taskAssembly": [
  { "qnt": 2300, "product": "non-INT", "labour": 12, "application":      "spray" },
  { "qnt": 2300, "product": "non-INT", "labour": 10, "application": "strips" }
    ]
  },
      {
       "taskName": "Pens",
       "taskQnt": 43,
        "taskLabour": 23,
        "taskAssembly": [
           { "qnt": 43, "product": "non-INT", "labour": 23, "application": "spray" }
           ]
       }
    ]}
```

my code is not exactly doing what I need.

```
      $scope.getTotalLabour = function(){
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.estimate.takeoff.length; i++){
      var item = $scope.estimate.takeoff[i];
      total += (item.taskLabour);
    }
    return $scope.estimate.totalLabour = total;
  }
```

any idea of how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check working demo: [JSFiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/RjqRf6rC0ZAqzIJJPiJJ?p=preview)

Simply create a nested loop like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.estimate.takeoff.length; i++){
  var total = 0;
  var item = $scope.estimate.takeoff[i];
  console.log(item);
  for (var j = 0; j < item.taskAssembly.length; j++) {
    total += (item.taskAssembly[j].labour);
  }
  item.totalLabour = total;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.  I apologize because I didn't explain correctly what I want to do. In the demo that you provided I want next to the ToW to have the sum of the 2 nested rows below it, it should be 22, and next to Pens the sum of the 2 rows below pens, it should be 43.

Comment: thank you.  I had to parseInt() the total and it worked.

Comment: My pleasure. In the demo, the data is in Number format, so no need to `parseInt`.